# How to solve this word problem on the topic of quadratic equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The maths teacher of Mumbai is transferred to another school. The students of Class 10 decided to buy a book for 360 rupees(currency) as a gift for her. On the farewell day, 4 students did not turn up and so those present had to contribute an extra 1 rupee each. How many students were there in the class all together?

#### Progress

Let the number of students in the class be $x$. I got $360/x$ as the cost of one student in the class.

Comment: What is your difficulty with this? How do you know it is a quadratic equation problem?

Comment: is in my question paper based on the the chapter "quadratic equation"

Comment: So how are you going to convert the information you have been given into equations?

Comment: If number of student in the class is x .I got 360/x as the cost of one student in the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x = $ number of students
$y = $ cost per student

$y=\frac{360}{x}$

$y+1=\frac{360}{x-4}$

Substitute $y=\frac{360}{x}$ into second equation:

$$\frac{360}{x}+1=\frac{360}{x-4}$$

$$(x-4)\frac{360}{x}+(x-4)=360$$

$$360-\frac{1440}{x}+x-4=360$$

$$-\frac{1440}{x}+x=4$$

$$-1440+x^2=4x$$

$$x^2-4x-1440=0$$

$$(x+36)(x-40)=0$$

$$x=40$$

We can ignore $x=-36$ because a class cannot have negative students. The class has $40$ students.

Comment: CAN YOU EXPLAIN SECOND AND THIRD STEP

Comment: We need to get rid of the $(x-4)$ in the denominator so I multiplied both sides by $(x-4)$. The third step was distributing the $(x-4)$. $(x-4)(\frac{360}{x})=x\cdot \frac{360}{x}-4\cdot \frac{360}{x}$. Does that help clear it up?

Comment: I still didn't get the third

Comment: Point out precisely what is causing the problem.

Comment: I want to know how you got "360-1440/x" in the third step

Comment: After multiplying both sides by $(x-4)$ we need to distribute (multiply) the $(x-4)$ to $\frac{360}{x}$. As stated above, $(x-4)\frac{360}{x}=x\cdot \frac{360}{x}-4\cdot \frac{360}{x}$. In the first term the x's cancel and you are left with $360$. The second term is simply $-4\cdot \frac{360}{x}=\frac{(-4 \cdot 360)}{x}=-\frac{1440}{x}$.

Comment: oh!now all clear thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there are $x$ students in the class.

The full class per-student book cost is ${360 \over x}$. We are told that  ${360 \over x-4}$ is one rupee more that the full class per-student cost. Appropriately equate the two and solve.

Comment: thank you for your information

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. Let $n$ be the number of students and $x$ be the cost per student. We are given two pieces of information:$$nx=360$$ and $$(n-4)(x+1)=360$$

If we equate $nx=(n-4)(x+1)$ we can get rid of the awkward term in $nx$ and get a linear relationship between $n$ and $x$, and substitute into either of the other equations to obtain a quadratic.

---

Namely $n=4x+4$, whence $nx=4x(x+1)=360$ and $x^2+x-90=0$ or $x(x+1)=90$

It depends how you want to solve the quadratic, but $x(x+1)$ is an increasing function for $x\gt 0$and it is clear that $x=9, n=40$ is the only positive solution.

Alternatively factorise as $(x+10)(x-9)=0$ or use the quadratic formula.